# Pass async data to child component with ngOnChanges does not work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-components

Following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components), precisely solution n 2, I've tried to pass async data to child component this way:

Parent component ts :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => { 
   this.networkService.getAttivitaById(this.idAttivita).subscribe((att:Attivita[]) => {
          this.attivita = att[0];
        })
  }
```

Parent component html:

```
<app-dettaglio-attivita [attivita]="attivita" [isModifica]="isModifica" [intervento]="intervento"></app-dettaglio-attivita>
```

And then child component:

```
@Input() attivita: Attivita;
[...]

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes['attivita']){
      this.initPage();
      console.log("LOADED " + this.attivita.id);
    }
  }
```

When I go to the page, in console it is printed, in order:

> cannot read property 'id' of undefined

referring to the line `console.log("LOADED " + this.attivita.id);` and right after I have:

[image]

It seems to catch two times the change. But what are the two changes? In the tutorial there's no word about this. How can I handle this without having the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if `currentValue` exists es well.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const { attivita } = changes;
    if (attivita && attivita.currentValue) {
      this.initPage();
      console.log("LOADED " + this.attivita.id);
    }
}
```